# Create commandbutton by cell value

Tags: excel, vba, cell, commandbutton

I am trying to get Excel to automatically create a commandbutton if a certain cell has text in it. Through running macro recorder and via googling, this is where I'm stuck.

```
Private Sub button()

If ActiveSheet.Range("C5") = Text Then

ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False _
    , DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=396.75, Top:=18.75, Width:=64.5, Height _
    :=26.25).Select
Selection.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try search the basic [syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/oleobjects-add-method-excel)  first ,
Make sure your cell C5 has value "Something"

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value = "Something" Then
            Dim button As OLEObject
            Set button = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False _
                       , DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=396.75, Top:=18.75, Width:=64.5, Height:=26.25)
        End If

    button.Object.Caption = "Complete"
    button.Name = "CommandbuttonEL1"

    End Sub
```

Comment: It works when I press F5 in VBA, but how can I make it appear automatically when typing "Something" in Cell C5 and press Enter?

Comment: I have updated the code , basically you need to put the code in worksheet selection change if you want it to work when you type in something and change the cell.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thanks. Do you also know how I can build on the code to change both the underlying name from Commandbutton1 to for example "CommandbuttonEL1" as well as change the caption to "Complete"?

Comment: When running the code it returns the following error message:

Object variable or With block variable not set

What am I doing wrong?
And how can I apply a slightly different version of the code should i want another button created on the same worksheet by using a reference from C6 instead of C5 used in this code?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @Erik I'm not getting any error while I'm running the code. To add one more condition you can add OR condition in IF statement.